# QgsMeshLayer in memory

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, mesh

I am trying to create a Meshlayer in memory and tried this simple test in QGIS 3.6:

`from qgis.core import QgsProject,QgsMeshLayer
proj = QgsProject.instance()
uri="1.0, 2.0 \n2.0, 2.0 \n3.0, 2.0 \n2.0, 3.0 \n1.0, 3.0 \n---0, 1, 3, 4 \n1, 2, 3 \n"
outLayer = QgsMeshLayer( uri, 'test', "memory_mesh")
proj.addMapLayer(outLayer)`

Apparently dataprovider has no attribute name and QGIS crashes.
Is there something that I am doing wrong? What shoulb be the format of `URI`, a simple string?

Comment: correct provider name is mesh_memory

Answer (score 3):

This is a mistake in the documentation. It needs to be `mesh_memory` and not `memory_mesh`. Also the documentation is missing one `\`.

So in QGIS 3.12 it works perfectly:

```
uri="1.0, 2.0 \n" \
    "2.0, 2.0 \n" \
    "3.0, 2.0 \n" \
    "2.0, 3.0 \n" \
    "1.0, 3.0 \n" \
    "---" \
    "0, 1, 3, 4 \n" \
    "1, 2, 3 \n"
scratchLayer = QgsMeshLayer(uri, "My Scratch layer", "mesh_memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([scratchLayer])
```

Comment: The documentation https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsMeshLayer.html?highlight=qgsmeshlayer#module-QgsMeshLayer is correct and the critical code snipped haven't changed for the last 3 years. In which doc you found the mistake?

Comment: Hi @Peter a bit of a long shot, after over a year, but I fixed that back in the days myself: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35218/commits/e6ff3c23729cd5d924343356e469068058718699 since it got accepted, I believe it was wrong before.

Comment: very good approach to fix it! thanks for that